# How to ask for user login when using SAML SOAP binding?

Tags: soap, binding, saml

I am learning SAML, and regarding SOAP binding, I am not sure how this works.

For redirect binding and post binding, it is very clear that SP can talk to IdP through browser then IdP can display a login screen if necessary.

But for SOAP binding, it doesn't need to go through browser, an SP can simply send an HTTP request which consist of a SOAP request to an IdP, then if IdP find that there is no valid user session, how can he display a login screen for user to input the username and password?

Or am I missing anything?

Answer (score 3):

Authentication is out of scope of the SAML spec. However, what SAML Profile are you looking at? Is this for Web SSO or something else? For Web SSO, SOAP is only used with the HTTP artifact binding which means you would either be resolving the AuthnRequest (IDP calling the SP) or retrieving the Response (SP calling IDP). The Artifact is sent either via POST or Redirect while resolution of the message (AuthnRequest or Response) is done via back-channel SOAP. So, the browser (http client) is always involved with Web SSO so it is simple for the IDP to authenticate the user via some browser-friendly technology (username/password HTML form, 2 factor strong auth, x509 certs, etc etc).

You can find an example in the SAML Bindings

```
POST /SamlService HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-Length: nnn
SOAPAction: http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/security
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
xmlns:SOAP-ENV=”http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/”>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<samlp:ArtifactResolve xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
ID="identifier_2"
Version="2.0"
IssueInstant="2004-12-05T09:22:04Z"
Destination="https://idp.example.org/SAML2/ArtifactResolution">
<saml:Issuer>https://sp.example.com/SAML2</saml:Issuer>
<samlp:Artifact>artifact</samlp:Artifact>
</samlp:ArtifactResolve>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The syntax might not be exact. Just something to give an idea.

Comment: Could you add an example for clarity?

Comment: An example of what? Please be more specific

Comment: a real life example of what a SOAP + artifact binding request would look like?

Comment: Check the SAML Bindings doc. Sect 3.2.3.5 -

Answer (score 0):

How the IdP chooses to authenticate the user is out of scope for SAML. If you're looking for an example, maybe there is a native application that displays a dialog box to the user, asking him to authenticate. Maybe the IdP sends you a text message through an SMS gateway and you have to respond to the text message in a certain way. The sky is the limit.